# NSMutableURLRequest POST 405 error Get

Tags: ios, swift, post

I know there are similar questions on stack overflow but nothing has solved my issue. 
I'm making a simple NSMutableRequest to a url and posting a simple string:

```
let locationString = "myString"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://exampleurl.com")!)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = locationString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }

    task.resume()
```

but I'm getting a 405 error: "Method GET not allowed"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus but I can't use NSJSONSerialization as the API call requires key/values be sent in order. I know it's not right but I have no control over this.

Comment: Could you explain why I'm getting that error with the current method?

Comment: A valid json object needs an array or dictionary as the root object. If you need to send just one string object, create a dictionary ["anyKey":"anyString"], convert it to data with dataWithJSONObject and add it to the HTTPBody

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, temporary at least until I can get the server side code changed to accept a JSON object regardless of order.

I constructed the JSON as a string with the correct order, used the method above and it works.